# How to make an input variable global in python 3.7?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm making a basic dice game and have created a process in which the the player can confirm their name or redo it. and the p1 variable i've used to store the players name only works within the function but I want to use it in the whole program

I've already tried define the variable before the function, which isn't working, and have tried writing Global before it in the function but it says "invalid syntax"

```py
#Functions
p1 = ""

def P1Start(): 
   print("Player 1 type your name")
   p1 =  str(input())
   print("Are you sure this is your name", p1)
   time.sleep(timesleep)
   print("Type YES to confirm")
   time.sleep(timesleep)
   print("Type NO to decline")

def P1Creation():
   P1confirmation = str(input()) 
   if P1confirmation =="yes":
        print("carry on")
        #elif P1confirmation == "NO" or "no":
        #P1Start()
        print(p1)
   else:
        print("Restarting the Player 1 Name Collection")
        time.sleep(1)
        P1Start()
#End of Functions

print("Welcome to the Dice game")
time.sleep(timesleep)
P1Start()
time.sleep(timesleep)
P1Creation()

print(p1)
```

or

```py
#Functions
p1 = ""

def P1Start(): 
   print("Player 1 type your name")
   global p1 =  str(input())
   print("Are you sure this is your name", p1)
   time.sleep(timesleep)
   print("Type YES to confirm")
   time.sleep(timesleep)
   print("Type NO to decline")

def P1Creation():
   P1confirmation = str(input()) 
   if P1confirmation =="yes":
        print("carry on")
        #elif P1confirmation == "NO" or "no":
        #P1Start()
        print(p1)
   else:
        print("Restarting the Player 1 Name Collection")
        time.sleep(1)
        P1Start()
#End of Functions

print("Welcome to the Dice game")
time.sleep(timesleep)
P1Start()
time.sleep(timesleep)
P1Creation()

print(p1)
```

Putting Global in front just shows "invalid syntax"
What should I do to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do a `global` and an assignment in one. Instead of this:

```
global p1 =  str(input())
```

Do this:

```
global p1
p1 =  str(input())
```

Comment: `input()` returns `str`, so `str(input())` is redundant.

Comment: @MarkTolonen Yes, but I wanted to show the minimal change to fix the OP's problem, not review/rewrite/improve the entire program.

Answer (score 0):

You can define it as global in your function itself.
Just an example:

```
def f(): 
        global s 
        s=" I am global"
        print(s) 

f()
print(s)
```